# it says NameError: name 'Doctor' is not defined when I try to execute

Tags: python

```
#Program that outputs quote for 3 jobs and outputs a sorry message >if an unrecognised job is used

#Subroutine to describe job
def Desc(Job):
    if Job == 1:
        print("Seeing what other people cant see gives you great vision")
    elif Job == 2:
        print("Logical thinking, passion and perseverance is the paint on your palette.")
    elif Job == 3:
        print("The engineer has been,and is,a maker of history.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, we could not find a quote for your job")

Analyst = 1
Developer = 2
Engineer = 3

#Main program
Desc(Doctor)
```

Comment: Yes, please "enter code here"... Please ask a question about a specific problem, have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Since this seems like homework, can you share exactly what you've been given, what you've done so far, and what work you think remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is all of the code, your error is caused because you do not have a variable defined that is called `Doctor`, so when you call `Desc(Doctor)` it cannot find a variable with that name. If you are going to use `Doctor` you need to define a variable with that name.

Edit to change my answer for what the poster is trying to do:

```
def Desc(Job):
   if Job == 'Analyst':
       print("Seeing what other people cant see gives you great vision")
   elif Job == 'Developer':
       print("Logical thinking, passion and perseverance is the paint on your palette.")
   elif Job == 'Engineer':
       print("The engineer has been,and is,a maker of history.")
   else:
       print("Sorry, we could not find a quote for your job")
```

Then you call your function like this:

```
Desc('Doctor')
```

Comment: but im trying to design the program so that any job name other than analyst, engineer, or developer is returned with a text saying "Sorry, we could not find a quote for your job"

Comment: If that is what you are trying to do then don't assign specific jobs to a number. Just pass in a job as a string use the string as your comparison. I will edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: oh i did that before assigning the numbers but i forgot to add apostrophe's thanks

Comment: Alright, if this answer is acceptable to you please don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set a variable 'Doctor'. You need write for example:

```
Doctor = 1
Desc(Doctor)
```